# why this query takes so much time to execute?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

is there is any better way to write this?

```
select Date, NeName, KPINAME, SUB_TYPE1, KPI 
from ggsn_kpi_2017 
where date 
    in ('2017-08-19', '2017-08-18', '2017-08-17', '2017-08-16', '2017-08-15', 
    '2017-08-14', '2017-08-13') 
    and KPINAME in('SM_SUCC_SESS_ACT_GGSN', 'SM_FAIL_SESS_ACT_GGSN', 'SM_SUCC_SESS_ACT_P_GW', 'SM_FAIL_SESS_ACT_P_GW', 
    'SM_SUCC_SESS_ACT_SAE_GW', 'SM_FAIL_SESS_ACT_SAE_GW', 
    'SM_DOWNLINK_BYTES_M2M', 'SM_UPLINK_BYTES_M2M') 

    group by Date, NeName, KPINAME 

    union 

    select Date, NeName, KPINAME, SUB_TYPE1, KPI 
    from ggsn_kpi_2016 
    where date in ('2017-08-19', '2017-08-18', '2017-08-17', '2017-08-16', 
    '2017-08-15', '2017-08-14', '2017-08-13') 
    and KPINAME in('SM_SUCC_SESS_ACT_GGSN', 'SM_FAIL_SESS_ACT_GGSN', 'SM_SUCC_SESS_ACT_P_GW', 
    'SM_FAIL_SESS_ACT_P_GW', 'SM_SUCC_SESS_ACT_SAE_GW', 
    'SM_FAIL_SESS_ACT_SAE_GW', 'SM_DOWNLINK_BYTES_M2M', 'SM_UPLINK_BYTES_M2M') 
    group by Date, NeName, KPINAME;
```

Comment: Please edit the question, format it properly, add the tags for the database you're using and also the query plan for it as well as table definitions, indexes etc. As it is nobody can say anything about it.

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what your issue is. This question is not a valid as a StackOverflow question. The guidelines on how to post a question are here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have `SUB_TYPE1, KPI ` in the `SELECT`, but they are not in the `GROUP BY`.  Your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just a guess, you don't have proper indexes. There's no much chance of giving any better advice with information you've given.

Comment: Some suggestions - Why you are using Group by when no aggregate function. Make sure to have proper indexes.

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question to provide the necessary information for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's one obvious performance antipattern in this query.  You have

```
where date in ('2017-08-19', '2017-08-18', '2017-08-17', '2017-08-16', 
'2017-08-15', '2017-08-14', '2017-08-13')
```

If `date` is `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, OR `DATE` column, change that to

```
where date >= '2017-08-13'
  and date <  '2017-08-20'
```

or even

```
where date >= '2017-08-13'
  and date <  '2017-08-13' + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Then create indexes on `(date, KPINAME)` for both tables. This will make your `WHERE` clause at least partly [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Also, you appear to be misusing `GROUP BY`. That goes with aggregate functions like `MAX()` and `AVG()`.  Do you mean `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Furthermore, you are checking `ggsn_kpi_2016` for days in 2017; this seems wrong?